# Increase the value of LimitRequestFieldSize in Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, configuration

I have developed an application which uses a jQuery plugin, which in turn uses excessive cookie data. The problem is, after every 15-20 request I am shown this error message by the browser:

> Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand. 
>   Size of a request header field exceeds server limit.

After digging around, I came to know by default apache has the default value of cookie length; somewhere around `8190 bytes`. To increase the limit, I need to change/add the directive below to my configuration.

```
LimitRequestFieldSize 16380
```

I tried adding the above code in `.htaccess`, and restarted the apache server too, but it didn't work.

I am confused on where to place this line; Is it in the `httpd.conf` file? Or is there any way I can increase the limit using the `.htaccess` file?  I would appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction.

**and BTW, I am on OSX 10.7.4 using MAMP.**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#limitrequestfieldsize) states the following:

```
Context: server config, virtual host
```

This means that that directive either goes into the global server configuration (anywhere in your `httpd.conf` file or in a file that gets included), or in one of the `VirtualHost` definitions. It won't work if you place it in an `.htaccess` file.

You should probably also review your application to see where that excess data comes from.

Comment: Thank you, I was trying to make it work via .htaccess and nothing seemed to work. I put it in httpd.conf, restarted apache and it now works.